# How to use enum with checkbox rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

I want to create a question list, to decide that question has multiple correct answer or not, I use a checkbox field:

```
<div>
  <%= ff.label :multi_correct, t(".multi"), class: "field-label" %>
  <%= ff.check_box :multi_correct %>
</div>
```

Here's my question model

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
...
  enum multi_correct: {no: 0, yes: 1}
end
```

When I submit the form, it returns an error said `'0' is not a valid multi_correct`

My schema.rb:

```
  create_table "questions", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "multi_correct"
```

How can I make this checkbox work? When it is unchecked it should send `0` to database and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh nvm, Here's the solution

```
<%= ff.check_box :multi_correct, {}, "yes", "no" %>
```

The first one is checked value, the second one is unchecked